# Join on a query returns more than one row

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a query

```
SELECT id_anything FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING (id_tables)
```

Now, i have a situation which is:

If that join returns two rows from table2 i want to show the id_anything from table1 (1 row only)
and if the join from table2 returns 1 row, i want to show id_anything from table2.

Ps: id_anything from table 2 returns different values

Example data:
table1

```
id_tables | id_anything
1         | 1
```

table2

```
id_tables | id_anything
1         | 10
1         | 100
```

Return expected: 1

Comment: Please add some sample data (as formatted text) and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: i added on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the value you may want to return and the basis for deciding which to return together into one row.

```
SELECT table1.id_tables, table1.id_anything AS table1_id, MIN(table2.id_anything) AS table2_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING (id_tables)
  GROUP BY table1.id_tables, table1.id_anything
```

The aggregate function you use doesn't really matter since you'll only be using the value if there is only one.

You can then pick the relevant value:

```
WITH join_summary AS (
  SELECT table1.id_tables, table1.id_anything AS table1_id, MIN(table2.id_anything) AS table2_id, COUNT(*) AS match_count   
    FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING (id_tables)
    GROUP BY table1.id_tables, table1.id_anything
)
SELECT id_tables, CASE WHEN (match_count > 1) THEN table1_id ELSE table2_id END AS id_anything
  FROM join_summary
```